# Eliminar los datos repetidos y sumar sus cantidades

Tags: java

Tengo un `ArrayList<>` de Productos donde guardo id , nombre , cantidad y quisiera saber, si tengo 2 productos con el mismo `id`, como hacerlo uno solo, Ejemplo:

```
id   Nombre   Cantidad

001  Galletas  2

001  Galletas  6

002  Arroz     7
```

y poder convertirla a:

```
id   Nombre   Cantidad

001  Galletas  8

002  Arroz     7
```

Mira te envio el codigo

```
List<Servicio> lista = new ArrayList();
    List<Servicio> repetidos = new ArrayList();
    lista.add(new Servicio(1, "Galleta", 2));
    lista.add(new Servicio(2, "Leche", 2));
    lista.add(new Servicio(1, "Galleta", 3));
    lista.add(new Servicio(2, "Leche", 4));
    Servicio se, se2;
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        se = lista.get(i);
        int suma;
        for (int j = 0; j < lista.size() && !repetidos.contains(se.getId()); j++) {

            se2 = lista.get(j);

            if (se.getId() == se2.getId()) {
                suma = se.getCantidad() + se2.getCantidad();
                System.out.println(suma);

            }
        }
    }
```

Al momento de comparse con el mismo se suma

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una condición que evalué el id, deberías de recorrer la lista y evaluar si el id esta repetido sume la cantidad

```
List<Integer> repetidos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < lista.size() && !repetidos.contains(lista.get(x)); y++) {
            if (lista.get(x).equals(lista.get(y)))
                //suma la cantidad
        }
```

Tener en cuenta que se crea una lista **auxiliar** para encontrar el id repetido, en este caso la lista auxiliar es "**repetidos**"

Comment: Te reescribi el codigo , Al momento de comparse con el mismo se suma

Comment: @MarceloArana Vale, según entiendo te esta dando el resultado de la cantidad de los los id's repetidos, lo ideal seria hacer un **.remove()** a uno de los elemento repetidos y le mandas el resultado a la Cantidad. **setCantidad()**

Comment: Logre solucionarlo poniendo y = i+1